# Characteristic of a ring $A$ and residue fields

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime number and $A$ be a commutative ring with unity. We say that $A$ has characteristic $p$  if $p\cdot 1_A=0$. I would like to know if you could have a ring $A$ with all residue fields (= $\operatorname{Frac}(A/\mathfrak{p}$) with $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal) of characteristic $p$ but $A$ itself not being of characteristic $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}.$ This has characteristic $4$, the only prime is $(2)$ and the residue field $\mathbb{F}_2$ is of characteristic $2$.

EDIT:
You may also say something positive (but not really surprising either):

> If $A$ is an integral domain such that all the residue fields are of equal characteristic $p$, then $\mathrm{char}(A)=p$.

This is because of the prime ideal $(0)$: in this case, we have $A \subseteq \mathrm{Frac}(A)=\mathrm{Frac}(A/(0)),$ and the claim follows.

Comment: I feel bad! That was obvious!

Answer (score 0):

Have you think in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=\{\frac{a}{b}\mid p\nmid b\}$?. This ring has charateristic $0$. But it is a local ring, with unique maximal ideal $p\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.  So its residue field $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/p\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the integeres modulo p.

Comment: There is one more residue field - $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Which is the  maximal ideal that gives you $\mathbb{Q}$ as quotient ring?

Comment: Not maximal, but the prime ideal $(0)$. : )

Comment: (0) gives you the original ring, which is a subring of the rationals, morover, this ring is local, meaning that it has an unique maximal ideal, so $(0)$ cannot be a maximal ideal.

Comment: No one is saying that the ideal is maximal. Read the OP's description of what he means by a residue field, if it does not coincide with your definition (the OP's definition seems standard, though). And $(0)$ cannot give you $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ as the residue _field_ - $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is not a field.

Comment: Your are saying that in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ there is another residue field $\mathbb{Q}$. First, there is no way to get $\mathbb{Q}$ as quotient of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.  You said that is using the ideal $(0)$, and you're claiming that is prime but not maximal, but as the quotient is a field, it must be maximal. It seems I lost some information. I have noticed that for residue field the question says prime ideal, but I assuming that a residue field is a field? Is that correct? =P

Comment: By definition, a residue field of a commutative ring $A$ at a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ is the _field of fractions_ of the integral domain $A/\mathfrak{p}$. Taking $A= \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ and $\mathfrak{p}=(0),$ this yields $A/\mathfrak{p}=\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, but the _fraction field_ of this is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thanks, that was claryfing,